# How to add a Card to ListView when the user clicks a '+' sign in the appBar?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I'm working on a flutter app. For now, I don't have much, but my question is, how I can add a card to a list (ListView) by clicking on a plus icon in the appBar? Code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Todo'),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            tooltip: 'Add a todo card',
            onPressed: () {`

            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

That is not the whole class, but the things you need to see.
I have my appBar and in it my IconButton.
That is how one of my card looks, it's a placeholder:

```
        children: <Widget>[
          Card(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                const ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.album),
                  title: Text('The Enchanted Nightingale'),
                  subtitle:
                      Text('Music by Julie Gable. Lyrics by Sidney Stein.'),
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TextButton(
                      child: const Text('BUY TICKETS'),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 8),
                    TextButton(
                      child: const Text('LISTEN'),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 8),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

I want to add this kinda card (custom) to ListView (body).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to achieve that:

1. Create a Stateless widget to extract your `TodoCard` as a separate widget.
2. Create a list of widget to hold your `TodoCard` widgets in the `TodoScreen`.
3. Add a single `TodoCard` in the `initState` so one will be rendered once the `TodoScreen` is built
4. When the add todo card is pressed, add a `TodoCard` to the list of widgets created and call `setState` to trigger a rebuild.
5. Render the list of `TodoCard` widgets in the `ListView` using the spread operator.

I added a demo using your code as an example:

**THE TODOCARD WIDGET**

```dart
// create a stateless widget to extract your TodoCard
class TodoCard extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          const ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.album),
            title: Text('The Enchanted Nightingale'),
            subtitle: Text('Music by Julie Gable. Lyrics by Sidney Stein.'),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                child: const Text('BUY TICKETS'),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 8),
              TextButton(
                child: const Text('LISTEN'),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 8),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**THE TODOSCREEN**

```dart
class TodoScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TodoScreenState createState() => _TodoScreenState();
}

class _TodoScreenState extends State<TodoScreen> {
  // create a list of widget to hold your TodoCard widgets
  List<Widget> _allCards = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // add a single TodoCard so one will be rendered once the page is built
    _allCards.add(TodoCard());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Todo'),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            tooltip: 'Add a todo card',
            onPressed: () {
              // when the add todo card is pressed, add a TodoCard to the list of widgets created and call setstate to trigger a rebuild
              setState(() {
                _allCards.add(TodoCard());
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          // reder the list of TodoCard widgets using the spread operator
          ..._allCards,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello. I wanted to thank you for your solution, it works. I just wanted to point out that if I leave the Todoscreen and access another screen and afterwards go back to the Todoscreen, the I added before aren't there anymore. How can I store the amount of Cards I had before so that Flutter can rebuild the screen with the right amount of Cards?

Comment: If you navigate from and back into the `TodoScreen` the `_allCards` list get re-initialized. You can save the state of the list of cards by storing in a database. You can check out `Sqflite` or `Hive` on https://pub.dev @Banik